# terraform output for another script

Tags: docker, ssh, terraform, amazon-ecs

i am new in terraform and jenkins, i have create docker image, which i have pushed in ecs with the help of ecs-cli and i have also created a another instance for graylog ([from this link](http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.4/pages/installation/aws.html)), now i want to send java system logs to graylog instance, for that i need to do some changes in java container and which require graylog instance ip.

```
output "instance_ips" {
value = "${aws_instance.web.public_ip}"}
```

with the help of above code i am able to get the ip of graylog server now i am confused how can i ssh in another server and update the ip so that i can get the java system logs, or i need to write a terraform script for run a container instead of using ecs-cli

**NOTE**: most important thing i am trying to automate this process so i can not do in manual way. e.g copy the graylog ip and ssh into java application and update the ip

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Terraform [Provisioners](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/index.html)

Using the [remote-exec provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/remote-exec.html) to execute `graylog-ctl set-external-ip ${aws_instance.web.public_ip}`

Using the [local-exec provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/local-exec.html) to write to the local configuration file and then use the [file provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/file.html) to upload the updated configuration file to your servers. Or just use the file provisioner setting the content and pushing that to your servers.

If you do require to SSH into the server and run the `graylog-ctl set-external-ip` command you can write a bash script that you can execute that use the `terraform output instance_ips` command like

> external_ip=$(terraform output instance_ips)